# Integrating Factor by Inspection $(x^3+xy^2+y)dx + (y^3+xy^2+x)dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$(x^3+xy^2+y) \hspace{.1cm} dx + (y^3+xy^2+x)\hspace{.1cm} dy=0$$ So I tried to solve this problem but can't figure out my integrating factor all I can see here is if I distribute first I can get a $y \hspace{.1cm} dx + x dy$ so that would be $d(xy)$ however I can't integrate the $xy^2dx$ and $xy^2dy$. Help please and can you also give me techniques on how to know the integrating Factors? My professors just told me that it's a trial and error process, is that true?

Comment: Are you **sure** it's not $x^2y$ in *one* term, and $xy^2$ in the *other* ? And are you sure that all signs are pluses ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is a typo in :
$$(x^3+xy^2+y) dx + (y^3+xy^2+x) dy=0$$
because it is not of standard level.

Hint : 
$$(x^3+yx^2+y) dx + (y^3+xy^2+x) dy=0$$
the integrating factor $(y^2+x^2-xy+2)$ is easy to find.

Comment: JJacquelin, may I ask how did you find the integrating factor? If we consider the equation in the form $F(x,y)dx + G(x,y)dy = 0$, and denote $\mu$ the integrating factor, finding it is equivalent to solving PDE $\mu_xG -\mu_yF = \mu(F_y-G_x)$. Solving it is easy if $\mu$ is independent of $x$ or $y$, but clearly, this is not the case here. So, is there a technique that I'm not aware of which simplifies the problem?

Comment: Hi Ennar ! In the wording of the question it is asked to find the integrating factor "by inspection". This suggests that it could be found by trying a few simple functions. The form of the equation suggests to first try polynomials. Moreover, there is a symetry between $x$ and $y$. Trying the simplest one : $(x+y+c)$ fails. Trying the second one $(x^2+y^2+axy+b)$, which takes account of the symetry, is successful and identifies $a=-1$ and $b=2$. Of course, it is not a general method;

Comment: Oh, alright. Thank you for clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$(x^3+xy^2+y)~dx+(y^3+xy^2+x)~dy=0$

$\dfrac{dx}{dy}=-\dfrac{y^3+xy^2+x}{x^3+xy^2+y}$

With reference to http://science.fire.ustc.edu.cn/download/download1/book%5Cmathematics%5CHandbook%20of%20Exact%20Solutions%20for%20Ordinary%20Differential%20EquationsSecond%20Edition%5Cc2972_fm.pdf#page=180:

Let $u=\dfrac{x}{y}$ ,

Then $x=yu$

$\dfrac{dx}{dy}=y\dfrac{du}{dy}+u$

$\therefore y\dfrac{du}{dy}+u=-\dfrac{y^3+y^3u+yu}{y^3u^3+y^3u+y}$

$y\dfrac{du}{dy}=-\dfrac{y^3(u+1)+yu}{y^3(u^3+u)+y}-u$

$y\dfrac{du}{dy}=-\dfrac{y^3(u^4+u^2+u+1)+2yu}{y^3(u^3+u)+y}$

$\dfrac{du}{dy}=-\dfrac{y^2(u^4+u^2+u+1)+2u}{y^3(u^3+u)+y}$

Let $v=\dfrac{1}{y^2}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{dy}=\dfrac{du}{dv}\dfrac{dv}{dy}=-\dfrac{2}{y^3}\dfrac{du}{dv}$

$\therefore-\dfrac{2}{y^3}\dfrac{du}{dv}=-\dfrac{y^2(u^4+u^2+u+1)+2u}{y^3(u^3+u)+y}$

$\left(\dfrac{2}{y^2}+u^3+u+1+\dfrac{1}{u}\right)\dfrac{dv}{du}=\dfrac{2}{uy^4}+\dfrac{2(u^2+1)}{y^2}$

$\left(2v+u^3+u+1+\dfrac{1}{u}\right)\dfrac{dv}{du}=\dfrac{2v^2}{u}+2(u^2+1)v$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.